LiteDb - find all documents having a subdocument whose id is part of a list
Here's my object model:
    class PhoneBookCategory
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<PhoneBook> PhoneBooks { get; set; }
    }

    class PhoneBook
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }


What I'm looking for is 'all PhoneBookCategories that have a PhoneBook whose Id is in a List. Or, in Linq Syntax
    List<Guid> myList = [Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()];
    GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>()
       .Find(u => u.PhoneBooks.Any(x => myList.Contains(x.Id));

LiteDB's Linq parser can't handle this, so I tried with the query syntax and ended up here:
    var bsArray = new BsonArray();
    myList.Foreach(u => bsArray.Add(u));
    GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>().Query()
       .Where(Query.In("$.PhoneBooks[*].Id ALL", bsArray))).ToList();

But what that gets me is this
    GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>()
       .Find(u => u.PhoneBooks == null || u.PhoneBooks.Count == 0)

instead. If I replace the ALL with ANY, I end up with no results.

you can try in this way.
I created a simple repository to centralize the functions and a test method to test the result.
    public class PhoneBookRepository
    {
      private ConnectionString _connectionString;
    
          private const string _categories_Collection = "categories";
          private const string _phoneBooks_Collection = "phoneBooks";
    
          public PhoneBookRepository(string fileName)
          {
              _connectionString = new ConnectionString(fileName);
          }
    

 public List<PhoneBookCategory> GetPhoneBookCategoriesFromPhoneBook(PhoneBook phoneBook)
          {
              using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_connectionString))
              {
                  var _categoryCollection = db.GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>(_categories_Collection);
    
                  var categories = _categoryCollection.Find(c => c.PhoneBooks.Select(pb => pb.Id).Contains(phoneBook.Id)).ToList();
    
                  return categories;
              }
          }

          public void AddPhonebook(PhoneBook pb)
          {
              using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_connectionString))
              {
                  db.BeginTrans();
    
                  var _collection = db.GetCollection<PhoneBook>(_phoneBooks_Collection);
    
                  _collection.Insert(pb);
    
                  db.Commit();
              }
          }
    
          public void AddPhoneBookCategories(PhoneBookCategory pbc)
          {
              using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_connectionString))
              {
                  db.BeginTrans();
    
                  var _collection = db.GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>(_categories_Collection);
    
                  _collection.Insert(pbc);
    
                  db.Commit();
              }
          }
    
         
      }

here is the test class with the test method:
  [TestClass]
  public class LitedbPhoneBookTest
  {
      [TestMethod]
      public void CanGetPhoneBookCategories()
      {
          var pb1 = new PhoneBook()
          {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
          };

          var pb2 = new PhoneBook()
          {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
          };

          var pbc1 = new PhoneBookCategory() {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
              PhoneBooks = new List<PhoneBook>()
              { pb1 }
          };

          var pbc2 = new PhoneBookCategory()
          {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
              PhoneBooks = new List<PhoneBook>()
              { pb2 }
          };

          var pbc3 = new PhoneBookCategory()
          {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
              PhoneBooks = new List<PhoneBook>()
              { pb1,pb2 }
          };

          var answerCodeRepository = new PhoneBookRepository("phoneBooks.db");

          answerCodeRepository.AddPhonebook(pb1);
          answerCodeRepository.AddPhonebook(pb2);

          answerCodeRepository.AddPhoneBookCategories(pbc1);
          answerCodeRepository.AddPhoneBookCategories(pbc2);
          answerCodeRepository.AddPhoneBookCategories(pbc3);

          var pbc1_result = answerCodeRepository.GetPhoneBookCategoriesFromPhoneBook(pb1);
          var pbc2_result = answerCodeRepository.GetPhoneBookCategoriesFromPhoneBook(pb2);

          Assert.AreEqual(2,pbc1_result.Count);
          Assert.AreEqual(2,pbc2_result.Count);
      }
  }

I hope this helps, let me know.

Your GetPhoneBookCategoriesFromPhoneBook takes one phonebook Id.. what I was looking for is one that takes a list of phonebook Ids. I eventually ended up writing this what I posted as a solution above.

Eventually I had to settle for doing this the hard way. I wrote this helper method:
internal static BsonExpression ReferencedTableContainsExpression(string listProperty, List<Guid> ids)
{
    return Query.In($"$.{listProperty}[*].$id ANY", GetArray(ids));
}

internal static BsonArray GetArray(List<Guid> ids)
{
    var bsArray = new BsonArray();
    foreach (var id in ids)
        bsArray.Add(id);
    return bsArray;
}

which can then be used as follows:
db.GetCollection<PhoneBookCategory>().Query().Where(ReferencedTableContainsExpression(nameof(PhoneBookCategory.PhoneBooks), ids));

